# Can Flot (or any other JQuery chart library) draw equations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I like to display data (x,y scatter) and a calculated curve `(F(x) = D+(A-D)/(1+(x/C)^B))` in the same graph.
I have tried `jqplot` and `flot`, but I could'n find a decent way to draw curves directly based on a equation.

Do I have to calculate a data set on my own, or is there a library able to draw directly from equations?

Comment: you have to turn the equations into javascript expressions.......

Comment: Just stumbled upon this: http://victory.formidable.com/ take a look at the first example.

Comment: very intersting. I keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any library doing this - so my solution was to write a short function returning a proper dataset. See my solution as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348974/logarithmic-sampling/36689034#36689034) to an other question.